# How to display a views' localized title (taxonomy term view)?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I am struggling to do what should be very simple and I am heading to a very complicated solution.

I have seen posts suggesting something like:

```
$view->page_title = t($view->page_title);
```

But this doesn't work because `$view->page_title` is simply not set in my view, even if I set the title manually.

I have tried this in a PHP snippet in the view's header and in the `views-view--page.tpl.php`:

```
$term = i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms(taxonomy_term_load($view->args[0]));
$view->page_title = t($term->name);
drupal_set_title($view->page_title);
```

Here `$view->page_title` gets set with the localized term name but the page's title is not set. I guess it is because the snippet is executed after the title is set. So I created a module:

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  print_r($view);
  if ($view->name == 'taxonomy_term_view') {
    $term = i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms(taxonomy_term_load($view->args[0]));
    $view->page_title = t($term->name);
    $view->build_info['title'] = $view->page_title;
  }
```

It works, but I have to create a condition for each and every taxonomy term view. I can't imagine this is the right way to do it. is there a simpler approach?